# Update Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

A situação é a seguinte, ao colocar a propriedade `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>`, nada mais funciona, nenhuma consulta funciona mais. o log sempre termina com

```
: jul 27, 2017 8:28:18 PM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@6974a715] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
```

se eu retirar essa propriedade de update, consigo fazer consultas normalmente, mas gerar tabelas, não... Não consigo gerar tabelas e eu preciso gerá-las a partir do Hibernate.

Esse é o meu `persistence.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="#####" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
                      value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                      value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@#####:#####:#####"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="#####"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="#####"/>

            <!-- propriedades do hibernate -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle8iDialect"/>
            <property name="show_sql" value="true"/>

            <!-- atualiza o banco, gera as tabelas se for preciso -->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>

            <!-- Configuring Connection Pool -->
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="10"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="3000"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="1800"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Se você colocar o log em DEBUG apresenta alguma mensagem de erro a mais?

Comment: não, nenhum erro.

Comment: Porque você precisa gerar as tabelas pelo Hibernate, não pode acessar o banco e criar as tabelas diretamente lá? Uma dica, nunca use essa propriedade em ambiente de produção, ela pode vir a te causar problemas, a própria documentação do Hibernate sugere esse recurso apenas para ambiente de desenvolvimento e não para produção. Você pode testar em outro banco de dados? Talvez o Oracle8iDialect tenha algum bug.

Comment: já mudei o Dialect e não resolveu

Comment: o banco é remoto e pra acessar o banco, preciso ta acessando remotamente o servidor e tem uma série de chatices nisso. eu queria evitar essas chatices.